# Can't launch gazebo simulation with my python code

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ros

I am using ROS Melodic in Ubuntu 16.04.
I am working with turtlebot 3 burger and trying out simulations on gazebo.
I have written a simple code to make the turtlebot move in a circle.

The code works perfectly as everything was working a couple of days ago.
Now when I try to launch it using

```
roslaunch assignment3_ws move.launch code:=circle
```

I get the following error:
[ERROR: could not contact master [https://localhost:11311]
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIejU.png)

I tried running it in every possible way.
With roscore, without roscore.
Even the network is setup properly in the bash file.

Can anyone provide a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the `ROS_MASTER_URI` environment variable to `192.168.1.162` ?

if you are using simulation and you need to set your `ROS_MASTER_URI` to `localhost`.

you only change `ROS_MASTER_URI` if you are trying to connect to remote ROS systems(Servers, other PCs, etc).